# Using newly released feature on an apex class having older API version

Tags: api-version, switch-case

As you all probably know [`switch` has been introduced in Summer'18](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html) (API v43,0) release.

I have started using it in my apex class which is having API version 36,0 and somehow it works in my sandbox. I was assuming it wouldn't be available hence throw an error or something like that.

My question is, is that a reliable/intended behavior or should I switch to API version 43,0 before deploying to production just to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch is not a versioned feature, presumably because they didn't want to force developers to upgrade to the latest API just to take advantage of this (and potentially trigger a large number of other required changes). As I've said before (in a another answer on this site), consider keeping all your classes the same version to avoid bugs. Only upgrade your API version when you have time to commit to a full upgrade/regression testing cycle.

Comment: It seems like most of the versioned changes relate to object definitions rather than code (e.g. trying to use `Platform Events` in a too-early version).

Comment: Keeping all classes at the same version was the exact reason for me to ask this since I don't want to (at least not yet) invest my time to upgrade/test 100+ classes. Also another thanks for 'versioned features/changes'. Seems like I have some research to do.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed the same thing and can only assume that while there is a versioning layer in APIs, the compiler may just always grow its syntax and not shrink its syntax. Or it could be that there is a versioning mechanism there and the addition of that logic has just been missed.

I've moved to version 43.0 to be on the safe side.